# How to get TD text by TH name?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to parse a doc, this code is like my code structure that I want to parse, I want to get TD text by TH name, How ?

```
<div id="m_PanelField">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="1" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Etat</th>
                <td>XyXy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>IP</th>
                <td>XX.XX.XX.XX</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Alias</th>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `//td[../th='Etat']` to get the first name, and so on

Comment: or `.//tr[th='Etat']/td`

Comment: Guys, you should post one of your xpath as an answer. And it should be accepted.

Comment: Yess, All are corrects answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//td[../th='Etat']` OR `.//tr[th='Etat']/td`

Thank's for @helderdarocha and @paul-trmbrth